# How reboot remote machine via ssh avoiding timeout?

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssh, paramiko, reboot

I have this part of code where I am trying to reboot a remote machine over ssh :

```
def check_and_reboot(ssh, hostname):
    # if not ssh_connect(ssh, hostname):
    #     print("SSH failed, restarting {}".format(hostname))
    # Step 2: If connection fails, reboot the machine
    if not reboot_machine(ssh, hostname):
        print("Failed to reboot machine {}. Exiting.".format(hostname))
        # return

    # Step 3: Run the command over SSH
    command = "ls -asl /raid/dfs/aiceph"
    ssh_connect(ssh, hostname)
    output, exit_code = execute_remote_command(ssh, command)

    # Step 4: If the command returns an error code, reboot the machine
    if exit_code != 0:
        try:
            # Execute the reboot command
            _, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("sudo nohup /sbin/reboot -f > /dev/null 2>&1 &")

            # Wait for the command to complete
            exit_status = stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()

            # If the exit status is 0, the reboot command was sent successfully
            if exit_status == 0:
                print("Reboot command sent successfully")
                return True
            else:
                print("Failed to send reboot command with exit status {}".format(exit_status))
                return False

        except Exception as e:
            # If there is an exception, print the error and return False
            print("Error sending reboot command: {}".format(str(e)))
            return False

    # Step 5: Validation successful
    print("Validation successful for machine {}".format(hostname))
```

I had set the exit_code = 1 to verify the flow. And it appears that my code happens to be stuck at step 4 as my code keeps waiting for the prompt from the reboot command. How can I overcome this without having to wait for the response from the reboot command?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking? Are you using `paramiko`, if so, consider adding that tag. Have you considered using `mosh`?

Comment: Yes, I am using paramiko. Haven't heard about mosh.

Comment: See https://mosh.org/

Answer (score 0):

An explicit `exit` should avoid the timeout problem.
But it is not reliable, when it is appended to the reboot command, like in

```
ssh <HOST> "sudo reboot now; exit 42"
```

This works sometimes, but not always (Race condition).

Therefore the connection should be closed, before the shutdown command is executed.

```
ssh <HOST> "nohup bash -c 'sleep 1; sudo reboot now' & exit 42"
```

This starts a new bash with `sleep 1; sudo reboot now` with nohup, so it runs even after the ssh connection is lost.
The `exit 42` should always executes before the sleep is done, but if you are paranoid or your system have a high load, you could couple it stronger.

```
ssh <HOST> 'nohup bash -c "tail --pid=$$ -f /dev/null; sudo reboot now" & exit 42'
```

This waits until the parent bash is closed by the `exit 42`